# Removing elements from auto generated JAXB schema

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jaxb2

Im generating a JAXB Marshalling-Unmarshalling Tool.
I have a set of annotated java classes, selecting all i auto generated JAXB schema in eclipse. I want to remove from schema, some of the fields which i dont want for some reason (May be later ill use them). I tried removed a field from schema like below

Schema Before removing

```
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="buildingNo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="buildingName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Schema after removing buildingNo

```
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="buildingName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

If i try to marshall address object based on above schema im getting error like `buildingNo not found instead found buildingName,....`

How to remove unused fields from schema??

Comment: Does your `Address` type still have a `buildingNo` field? You can add `@XmlTransient` to have the marshaller ignore it.

Comment: Yes buildingNo field still exists for other Application. If i insert @XmlTransient it will be ignored for other application also. So i thought 2 different schema for 2 applications. 1st requires the buildingNo and 2nd doesnt require field buildingNo???

Comment: yes, you need 2 schemas; and having 2 schemas is the right choice. Different scenario need a different mapping; now is just a buildingNo but later? Maybe more changes will be required and schemas need to grow up in 2 completely different manners.

Comment: Even if i wanna have different schemas, my java classes structure remains same, Thats why i want to achieve this removal of unused element in schema1. Please suggest, How to do this?

Comment: optional and nillable can be a solution if you may change buildingNo to `JaxbElement<>`